# Doctrine 2 : Best way to store different information

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'd like to know what are the best practises to have different information stored depending on some variables.

For example, I have a `ServerEntity`, I want to store the disks plugged on this server with a `ServerDiskEntity`.

- If this disk is SSD, I want to store the NAND type (MLC, SLC, TLC).
- If this disk is HDD, I want to store the RPM.

Then, when I request `ServerEntity->getDisks()`, I check if the type is SSD, display the NAND type, if HDD type display RPM.

Storing everything in the same entity looks awful to me. Having two separate entities (with nothing else gluing them together) is not an option because I store some other information such as tray number.

My closest guess is : `ServerDiskEntity` stores `DiskType` and `DiskId`, and I use this information to `getRepository(diskType)->findOneBy(["id" => $DiskId])` but this also seems very non optimised from my POV.

Please someone teach me some magic to have a clean way to do this (and I'd like to avoid using ElasticSearch :D )

Answer (score 0):

Single Table Inheritance (or Joined Table Inheritance) is the answer :

https://digitalfortress.tech/php/configure-doctrine-multiple-target-entities/